# Saving picture to app directory returns null in onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent

I am saving an image to the application directory by using the following with my intent (Got it from the android dev site):

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
        File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
        return image;
    }
```

And then in the `onClick`:

```
File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "File not created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (photoFile != null){
                    Intent camIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    camIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    getActivity().startActivityForResult(camIntent, 0);
                }
```

Up to here it works perfectly fine. I checked in the app dir using my file manager and the pictures get saved and they cannot be seen by other apps, as it should be. The problem is that when I try to display it in my `ImageView` I get a `NullPointerException`. This is the problem code:

```
private void setCameraPicture(int picture_count, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "picture = " + selectedImage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String camPictureString = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage);
            File f = new File(camPictureString);
            ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(camPictureString);
            int rotation = 0;
            int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
                rotation = 90;
                bm = rotateCameraImage(rotation, f);
            } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
                rotation = 180;
                bm = rotateCameraImage(rotation, f);
            } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
                rotation = 270;
                bm = rotateCameraImage(rotation, f);
            } else {
                bm = rotateCameraImage(rotation, f);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IOException", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NullPointerException", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
```

The line `Uri selectedImage = data.getData();` returns null. Am I doing this wrong? I call the `setCameraPicture()` from my `onActivityResult()` and pass the `Intent data` in as a parameter.

This code works fine if I don't save to the application directory. Do any of you have any suggestions? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the device model you're running this code on?

Comment: @Melquiades At the moment I am testing on a Samsung Galaxy S3 LTE

Comment: Just save a reference to the File object before you launch the camera intent. Then use bitmapfactory on activity result.

Answer (score 0):

`getData()` returns null because you've specified a custom file to save the Image in (`Media.EXTRA_OUTPUT`). The data is stored in the path that you've specified, and not returned in your `onActivityResult()`. This makes sense because there is no reason to return it if the data is already stored somewhere. Just simply retrieve the Bitmap image from the path.

Comment: Well, how can I get that path in my onActivityResult? Or do you think that I should just pass it to my onActivityResult using a bundle?

Comment: Are all those methods in the same activity/fragment? If so, you can just make a global variable that holds the reference to the file. Like this: private File photoFile;